# Looking for a list of oracle forms item properties

Tags: oracleforms

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a list posted anywhere that has all the properties for oracle forms (6i preferably) items and the names I need to use to get them via the get_item_propery() function. We have some books on oracle forms at work but none of them seem to have a comprehensive list of properties. I've also googled it, but maybe I'm google impaired on this particular topic.

Failing finding a complete list, does anyone know what the property name for an item's comments would be, assuming I can get it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the online help that comes with Oracle Forms? Launch Forms builder, Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> & search for `get_item_property`, you'll get a list of all item properties.